# Extracting 2 parts of a String

Tags: string, bash, extract, cut

I've got a String which contains the Output of a command which looks like this:

```
max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')
```

Now I need to extract the "2.5 MBit/s" and the "16.7 MBit/s" in two seperate strings.

The language is bash.

Comment: What did you tried until now? Show us the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with awk:

```
string1=$(echo "max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')" | awk -F"'" '{print $2}')
string2=$(echo "max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')" | awk -F"'" '{print $4}')
```

with cut:

```
string1=$(echo "max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')" | cut -d"'" -f2)
string2=$(echo "max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')" | cut -d"'" -f4)
```

Either way we are just splitting the string by a single quote and grabbing the 2nd and 4th fields.

Answer (score 2):

Like this in `bash` without starting any extra external processes:

```
yourString="max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')"

IFS="'" read _ rate1 _ rate2 _ <<< "$yourString"

echo $rate1
2.5 MBit/s

echo $rate2
16.7 MBit/s
```

I am setting the IFS (Input Field Separator) to a single quote, then doing a `read` with unwanted fields going into a dummy (unused) variable called `_`.

Answer (score 1):

With regex:

```
x="max. bit rate:      ('2.5 MBit/s', '16.7 MBit/s')"
[[ $x =~ .*\'(.*)\'.*\'(.*)\'.* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Output:

```
2.5 MBit/s 16.7 MBit/s
```